# Process taking lots of time in foreach loop in C#

Tags: c#, tridion

I am using C# code and Tridion(CMS) classes to fetch data from Tridion, below is the code to get all the publications List from Tridion.

```
protected void btnPublishPublicationList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            PublicationBL pubBL = new PublicationBL();
            TridionCollection<Publication> pubAllList = pubBL.getAllPublicationList();
            List<PublicationsBO> pubBos = new List<PublicationsBO>();

            foreach (Publication pub in pubAllList)
            {
                if ((pub.Title.StartsWith("07"))||(pub.Title.StartsWith("08")))
                {
                    PublicationsBO pubBO = new PublicationsBO();
                    pubBO.publicationID = pub.ID;
                    pubBO.publicationName = pub.Title;
                    pubBos.Add(pubBO);
                }
            }

            pubBL.createPublicationListXML(pubBos);          
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

In above code on the button click, I am using .net code and using Tridion class to get all the publications List as below:

```
TridionCollection<Publication> pubAllList = pubBL.getAllPublicationList();
```

I am getting my all the publications list very fast from the Tridion, however when I am going for **foreach** loop as below my process gets stuck and it takes lots of time to do this.

```
foreach (Publication pub in pubAllList)
            {
                if ((pub.Title.StartsWith("07"))||(pub.Title.StartsWith("08")))
                {
                    PublicationsBO pubBO = new PublicationsBO();
                    pubBO.publicationID = pub.ID;
                    pubBO.publicationName = pub.Title;
                    pubBos.Add(pubBO);
                }
            }
```

After debugging I found that when debugger comes to `foreach (Publication pub in pubAllList)` it is taking lots of time. I think while making the **Publication** class object is taking time and it is Tridion class.

Please suggest any other way to do this or suggest what is wrong in above code.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe TridionCollection enumerator is lousy?

Comment: What does this mean, please suggest

Comment: Try iterate it as per normal by index or key (dont know the nature of this class) and see if there is any difference. Other explanation is lazy load as suggested below.

Just in case i would suggest also to see memory usage during this operations...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to [this](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/GenericCollections.aspx) which I think is the developers site... it looks like getAllPublicationList is using some sort of lazy loading so even though you have the collection you don't really have the items in it.

It appears that you can set filters on their collection rather than after the fact so that it will only load the records you are interested in.

to clarify, lazy loading means that when the collection is returned the data needed to populate the items in it are not yet laded.  It isn't until you access the item in the collection that the data (e.g. by creating a Publication item) for that item is actually loaded.  The purpose for using a lazy collection is to allow filtering on the collection so that unnecessary expensive loads can be avoided.

HTH

Comment: My Dear Friend Yaur, The list is not taking any time, the time is taken only when I am going to make Publication class object

Comment: @Manu I added some text to the answer, the behavior you are describing is consistent with what would be expected when enumerating through a lazy collection.

Comment: Thanks @Yaur, can you please suggest what I can do for avoiding lazy loading.

Comment: @Manu you can't avoid it and if you could you would be back here asking why the collection took so long to create.  What you need to do is work with it.. it looks like they want you to use something called a `ListRowFilter` to prefilter the collection before you enumerate it.

Answer (score 5):

It is indeed because of Tridion's lazy-loading. If all you need is a list of Publication IDs and Titles, I'd recommend using:

```
TDSE tdse = new TDSEClass():
XmlDocument publicationList = new XmlDocument();
publicationList.LoadXml(tdse.GetListPublications(ListColumnFilter.XMLListIDAndTitle));
```

This will give you an XML document containing a list of all publications (/tcm:ListPublications/tcm:Item), and each Item will contain a Title and ID attributes.

If you need more detail than just ID and Title, then you will have to individually load each publication, which you can do by using the ID attribute tdse.GetObject().

Hope this helps.
N